# Can we use SQLTransaction in Windows Powershell ISE?

Tags: powershell

I tried using SQLDataAdapter Object in Powershell ISE and its methods like below

```
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
```

and used its method like below

```
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
```

Its working for me. But when I am trying like below

```
$trans= New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction
```

and using its method like this

```
$trans = $connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction")
```

where

```
$connection= New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
```

Its giving me error

> Exception calling "BeginTransaction" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid
>   operation. The connection is closed." At line:1 char:41
>   + $trans = $SqlConnection.BeginTransaction <<<< ("SampleTransaction")
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Anybody having any idea on this??

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't opened the connection.

Are you simply missing:

```
 $connection.Open();
```

That would be my first guess.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gisli on opening a connection. Where's the rest of your code? Another approach is to use a command object and assign the command transaction property to the command:

```
$cmd=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql,$conn)
$cmd.Transaction = $transaction
```

This is what we do in the adolib module which is part of [SQL Server Powershell Extensions](http://sqlpsx.codeplex.com/). Check out Modules\adolib\adolib.psm1.